# Как использовать ключи в React для удаления элемента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Изучаю React. Подскажите, пжлст, каким образом здесь я могу обратиться к key чтобы использовать его в функции удаления элемента? Благодарю.

```js
import CommentItem from './CommentItem';
// import uuid from 'react-uuid'

function CommentList(props) {
    const {comments} = props;

    function removeCommentItem() {

        // если элемент содержит key, который принадлежит конкретному элементу,
        // то этот элемент нужно удалить
        // filter берет исходный массив и удаляет из него всё, что не соответствует условию,
        // то есть, оставляет в новом массиве только те элементы, которые не содержат данный key

        alert('Клик по кнопке "Удалить" работает')
    }

    return (
        <ul className="CommentList list">
            <h2 className="second-title CommentList-title">Все комментарии</h2>

            {comments.map((comment, i) => {
                return <CommentItem
                    key={i}
                    userName={comment.userName}
                    commentText={comment.commentText}
                    currentDate={comment.currentDate}
                    currentTime={comment.currentTime}
                    removeItem={removeCommentItem}
                />
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default CommentList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё. Вопрос снят. Нужно просто передать его в качестве аргумента:

```js
removeItem={() => removeCommentItem(uuid(i))}
```

И, да, конечно, не следует использовать индекс. Я здесь применил uuid().